# Echo the name of all the files to the server arrived through post

Tags: php

How to echo the temporary name of all files to the server arrived through post with PHP?

Comment: you mean by $_FILES, right ?

Comment: print_r($_FILES) should get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    $tmp[] = $file['tmp_name'];
}
print_r($tmp);
```